# When a divisor on an algebraic curve is canonical

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I am trying to solve this:

> If $D$ is a divisor over a algebraic curve X of genus $g$ such that
>   $\deg(D)=2g-2$ and $\dim L(D)=g$, then $D$ is a canonical divisor

Using Riemann-Roch theorem, being $K$ an canonical divisor over $X$, I have:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\dim L(D)-\dim L(K-D)=\deg(D)+1-g\\
\dim(K-D)=1
\end{array}
$$

By Serre's duality,
$$
\dim L(K-D)=\dim L^{(1)}(-D)=1
$$

This means that there exists only one 1-form $\omega \in L^{(1)}(-D)$ such that $ord_p(\omega)\geq D(p)$, for all $p\in X$.

I don't know how to finish this. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Riemann and Roch are two people, so it's just the "Riemann–Roch theorem".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have successfully shown that $h^1(O_X(D))=1,$ i.e., that $h^0(\mathcal O_X(K-D)) = 1.$ Now try Riemann-Roch again: $$h^0(\mathcal O_X(K-D))-h^1(\mathcal O_X(K-D))=\deg(K-D)+1-g,$$ and using that $h^1(\mathcal O_X(K-D))=h^0(\mathcal O_X(D))$ we get that $\deg(K-D)=0.$

Now apply Hartshorne Lemma IV.1.2, which gives $K-D\sim 0,$ i.e., $K\sim D.$

Comment: Can I use the following: since $k$ is canonical then $deg(k)=2g-2$ therefore $deg (K-D)=0$?

Comment: Dear @GustavoMarra, yes, that seems reasonable, since the degree map is a homomorphism after all.

Comment: @Marra the key point of this argument is that when $deg(D) = 2g - 2$, $K-D$ always has degree $0$, but it is only the trivial divisor class (hence has $L(K-D)=1$ instead of $0$) when $D\sim K$.